# Popscene menu touch issues cocos2dx

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

i am developing a game that has subview in it so i have used pushscene and popscene but i have encountered a problem. When i push scene of subview i write popscene to close it.

i have one selection scene having 6 ccmenu in it and on ccmenu click action i have called pushscene. now when i popscene and come back to my selection screen that is having 6 ccmenu, i am not getting menu touch event.

what should i do??

code in selection screen

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pushScene(level1::scene());
```

code in level1

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->popScene();
```

note:
i am not using cocos2dx3.0

Comment: Could you provide more code. It's difficult to figure out what might prevent your menu's items to get the touch event without more details.

Comment: Check that the pushed scene properly deallocates on pop. If it does not, the touches not responding is one kind of issue you may get.